# Merged commits listed as unmerged in branch diff

Tags: git

Consider a repo with the following branches:

`master: A-B-C-D-E`

`development: A-B-C-D-E-F-G`

When I run `git log master..development --oneline` I receive the following:

```
C <hash> <commit message> 
D <hash> <commit message>
E <hash> <commit message>
F <hash> <commit message>
G <hash> <commit message>
```

So even though `C D E` are in both branches, they are reported as unmerged. Furthermore, when I attempt to merge `development` into `master`, it will duplicate the commits, one with the original commit hash, and the other with a new commit hash.

I've inherited the repository and I'm wondering what might have caused such an issue, if I should be concerned, and what the best course of action is. I need to merge in the new commits `F G` into master and I'm trying to figure out the best approach to keep things as clean as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this to be the case, they have to be *different* commits (by ID), if I have not mis-read your case. Try `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --left-right master...development` (note three dots); maybe add `--boundary` to this to get the boundary commit(s) shown as well. That should help define the problem more precisely, at least.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not entirely sure as to the reason why this is happening, I have an idea on how you can merge the branches without creating these duplicates commits.

The solution is to use `git cherry-pick`. Cherry-pick will replay specific commits onto the tip of your current branch without regard to commit history, but only works well if the commit can apply cleanly to the new branch (which should be fine so long as both versions of `C D E` have the same changes.

First, make sure you are on your master branch. From there, do the following command:

```
$ git cherry-pick F G
```

Make sure that F and G are the respective commits' hashes.

If this command fails, I would be willing to bet that `C D E` are not actually the same commits on both branches.

If you want us to debug *why* this might be happening, it would be very useful to post the results of `git log master..development`, redacting any information as necessary.